# Trying to install Ubuntu Studio via USB, I only see the GRUB menu?

Tags: grub2, live-usb, bootloader, ubuntu-studio

For some reason, and this happened when I tried to install Kubuntu as well, when booting from the Ubuntu ISO I only see the GRUB menu. I have no option to install or to go to the live boot from USB. What am I doing wrong?
video of what is happening:
https://youtu.be/PVEJxvWvRB0

Comment: And what you see in grub menu? What are the options?

Comment: Nothing, just the grub menu. Like it automatically just goes to "GNU GRUB 2". When looking at tutorials other people got the option to choose their language first, but I didn't get that option...

Comment: This is not a menu then.

Comment: https://youtu.be/PVEJxvWvRB0 I recorded what happens when I boot, would this help?

Comment: This is not a menu, but grub prompt. Something is wrong with the flash drive.

Comment: Are you sure? Because I've used the flash drive to install Pop OS fairly recently, and before installing pop OS I tried to install KDE and got this same issue. Is this something repairable or do I need a new flash drive?

Comment: If you add `maybe-ubiquity` to the linux line in your grub.cfg menuentry you will get the choice to go to the Language/Install screen when booting. Let me know if you need a full answer.